# Karate Not getting response cookies when upgraded to 1.0.0

Tags: karate

Earlier, I was using karate 0.9.6 and I was able to fetch JSESSIONID from the response. I need this cookie to set in the next API call. Today, when I upgraded t0 1.0.0, I am not able to fetch this cookie anymore.

Is there any public free API, which I can use to reproduce this cookie issue ?

```
Scenario: Get API Access Token
    * def consumerResponse = call read('classpath:helper/auth/GenAuthHeader.feature@getConsumerKeySecret')
   * print 'check this -->', consumerResponse.responseCookies.JSESSIONID
```

OUTPUT
In 0.9.6

```
11:08:14.570 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] check this --> {
  "name": "JSESSIONID",
  "value": "ZA3F-D1sPUso4J-6Q9P7fprL.com1-18",
  "domain": "true-azre1-qa3-api.sephora.com",
  "path": "/v1",
  "persistent": "false",
  "secure": "false"
}
```

In 1.0.0

```
Looks like in newer version, cookies are embedded in responseHeaders object which contains Set-Cookie []
```

Comment: my bad, i should have done ling time back.

Comment: I am also facing same cookie issue when upgrading to karate 1.0.0 or 1.0.1. I am getting following error while execution:
`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "responseCookies" is not defined - <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)`
 
We did not face this issue with Karate 0.9.6 earlier.